# how do I get a list of old and new wordpress post urls if I change the permalink structure?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I used the default wordpress permalink structure.  I know want to use the postname.  To create 301 redirects I assume I need to get a list of posts with the old and new urls?  Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If the slug's didn't change, WordPress should automatically arrange this for you. Did you try?